# create NetSuite ItemFulfillment containg items with lot/serial info

Tags: c#, netsuite

I am using SuiteTalk web services (v. 2013_2) .  I am trying to create an ItemFulfillment where the items in it were related to items that had a lot or serial number.

When I try to save this item fulfillment into NetSuite I get an error of :
`Please commit inventorydetail on this line.`

I was attempting to set the `itemFulfillment.serialNumbers`  and `itemFulfillment.binNumbers` when I create the `itemFulfillmentItem`.

For example I set

```
nsIfItem.serialNumbers = "SNum(5)"
nsIfItem.binNumbers = "BNum(5)"
```

based on those properties being-  A comma delimited list of serial or LOT numbers. If entering serial numbers there must be a number for each item. 
             Lot numbers must be entered in a format of LOT#(Quantity). 
             For example, to enter a quantity of 100 items as Lot number ABC1234, enter ABC1234(100).

Do I also need to set something else on the `itemFulfillment` or how do I get rid of that error.

Comment: Do you have the Advanced Bin Management / Numbered Inventory Management feature enabled? Also, what end point are you using?

Comment: I am not sure.  How would I check that?  As for the endpoint version we are using 2013_2.  Sorry I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Setup -> Company -> Enable Features -> Items & Inventory. Should be on the right side, approx half way down

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure it entirely matters, however the help system makes reference to it. I think you'll be able to get by with either adding ` item.itemReceive = true;
                    item.itemReceiveSpecified = true; ` or ` item.itemIsFulfilled = true;
                    item.itemIsFulfilledSpecified = true;`, but I haven't tested that theory

Comment: I shall give those a try.  thanks a lot for suggesting some paths to take.  I shall post how that goes when I have a moment to try it out.

Comment: Sadly there must be more to it that that.  I have set up both of those values to be true and still have the issue.

Comment: Can you post your full IF code? I'll try to reproduce

Comment: Thanks alot.  it would be difficult to based on how my code works but i can maybe at least post the request we are sending to them if you think that may help?

Comment: The more data the better :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this question is still active, but I had the same issue and iI couldn't find much help on it. I solved this issue by creating the inventory assignment objects and adding to the transaction.

First, create the initialize ref for Item Fulfillment and assign the returned record to a variable:

```
InitializeRecord ir = new InitializeRecord();
ir.type = InitializeType.itemFulfillment;

InitializeRef iref = new InitializeRef();
iref.typeSpecified = true;
iref.type = InitializeRefType.salesOrder;

iref.internalId = 'Sales Order internalID';
ir.reference = iref;

ReadResponse getInitResp = _service.initialize(ir);

ItemFulfillment ifrec = (ItemFulfillment)getInitResp.record;
```

Get the list of items on the initialized transaction:

```
ItemFulfillmentItemList ifitemlist = ifrec.itemList;
```

Create a list to which to add each unique item being fulfilled:

```
List<ItemFulfillmentItem> ifitems = new List<ItemFulfillmentItem>();
```

Run the following code for each item in initialized transaction's item list:

If the current line item has already been added to the ifitems list, add the current Fulfillment line as an assignment to that item:

```
InventoryAssignment assignment = new InventoryAssignment
{
    issueInventoryNumber = new RecordRef { internalId = 'internalID',
    type = 'RecordType',
    typeSpecified = true 
    }
};
List<InventoryAssignment> list = new List<InventoryAssignment>();

list.Add(assignment);
ifitemlist.item[b].inventoryDetail = new InventoryDetail
{
     inventoryAssignmentList = new InventoryAssignmentList
     {
         inventoryAssignment = list.ToArray()
     }
};
ifitemlist.item[b].quantity += 'quantity shipped';
```

If the line item has not yet been added, create new line item:

```
ItemFulfillmentItem ffItem = new ItemFulfillmentItem();
ffItem.item = ifitemlist.item[b].item;
ffItem.itemReceive = true;
ffItem.itemReceiveSpecified = true;
ffItem.itemIsFulfilled = true;
itemIsFulfilled = true;
ffItem.itemIsFulfilledSpecified = true;
ffItem.orderLineSpecified = true;
ffItem.orderLine = ifitemlist.item[b].orderLine;

//Check if serialized
if (Your fulfillment item contains serialized data)
{
    ffItem.serialNumbers = 'Serial numbers';
    InventoryAssignment assignment = new InventoryAssignment
    {
         issueInventoryNumber = new RecordRef { 
         internalId = 'Inventory internal ID',
         type = RecordType,
         typeSpecified = true 
         }
    };
    ffItem.inventoryDetail = new InventoryDetail
    {
        inventoryAssignmentList = new InventoryAssignmentList
        {
            inventoryAssignment = new InventoryAssignment[]
            {
                 assignment
            },
            replaceAll = false
        },
        nullFieldList = new string[] { },
        customForm = new RecordRef { }
     };
 }

 ffItem.quantity = 'QUANTITY SHIPPED';
 ffItem.quantitySpecified = true;
 ifitems.Add(ffItem);
```

Finally, add your "ifitems" list to your Item Fulfillment and add this to NetSuite:

```
ItemFulfillmentItemList ifitemlistToFulfill = new ItemFulfillmentItemList();
ifitemlistToFulfill.replaceAll = false;
ifitemlistToFulfill.item = ifitems.ToArray();

ItemFulfillment newItemFulfill = new ItemFulfillment();
newItemFulfill.itemList = ifitemlistToFulfill;
_service.add(newItemFulfill);
```

Comment: Is it possible to add serielnumbers while creatting fulfilment

Comment: How do you get the internalID used on this line? issueInventoryNumber = new RecordRef { internalId = 'internalID
All I have it the actual Lot #.